# Getting error while installing ffi gem

Tags: ruby, bundle, ffi

```
$ jruby -S bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from http://controller.c3.mtv:8008/....
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from http://controller.c3.mtv:8008/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using ansi (1.4.3)
Using builder (3.2.2)
Installing ffi (1.9.2)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

        c:/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ffi-
1.9.2 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ffi-1.9.2/ext/ffi_c/g
em_make.out
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

This was the error when i did a bundle update so i did the following as suggested above in last line

```
    $ gem install ffi -v '1.9.2'
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            c:/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb

    make
    'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

Gem files will remain installed in c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ffi-
1.9.2 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ffi-1.9.2/ext/ffi_c/g
em_make.out
```

Then i tried the following

```
$ gem install ffi
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ffi-
1.9.2 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ffi-1.9.2/ext/ffi_c/g
em_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Looks like a Windows error message..do you have `make` installed on your system? I'd check out [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to avoid getting dependency issues on unix tools.